# Microsoft Graph API: assignments(plannerAssignment) property of Task Resource(plannerTask ) is not working

Tags: azure, graph, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Hi I am making post request to graph api(Beta) to create a task with assignee as follows.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/planner/tasks",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer token",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "f6dd56ab-6fb4-f553-74aa-792945ba98b6"
  },
  "data":  {"title": "testTask","planId": "rPWMLzwXlUOA33dPNU9-dWUAAoRf,  "assignments": {"7d0544e0-2ed9-4aab-92a0-38efcaa292cd": {"orderHint": '5637'    } } }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

But it gives Error as follows,

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "14a2ef00-a271-4be8-8197-71aa46379017",
      "date": "2017-04-18T11:29:42"
    },
    "innererror": {
      "message": "task : An error has occurred.\r\n"
    }
  }
}
```

Task resource link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/plannertask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with the request.

- For open type properties, you need to include the type of the complex type value of the property, in this case "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment".
- The order hints sent in the request follow the format described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/planner_order_hint_format), your input isn't valid according to that format. In this case, since this is the first item, the order hint should be " !". You can use " !" for all order hints to have one generated for you, if you don't care about the order of items.

After making necessary changes, your request should look like this:

```
{"title": "testTask","planId": "rPWMLzwXlUOA33dPNU9-dWUAAoRf, "assignments": {"7d0544e0-2ed9-4aab-92a0-38efcaa292cd": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.plannerAssignment", "orderHint": " !"} } }
```